# Because budgets depends on flutter_cupertino_localizations any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

Iam using Flutter 3.10.5
I tried cloning project from github but this error is raised while pub get [Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.5.

Because budgets depends on flutter_cupertino_localizations any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHSIJ.png)

i tried adding --no-sound-null-safety also but nothing works.
If anyone can help me i'll be grateful

Answer (score 0):

You're on a version of Dart that is fully null safe, therefore all your packages/dependencies have to support null safety. [flutter_cupertino_localizations](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_localizations) is not null safe. I'll suggest looking for an alternative for that package which is null-safe.

Comment: After resolving that again this error is raised
Resolving dependencies...
Because google_fonts >=4.0.5 depends on http ^1.0.0 and firebase_storage_web >=1.0.0 depends on http ^0.13.0, google_fonts >=4.0.5 is incompatible with firebase_storage_web >=1.0.0.
And because firebase_storage >=11.2.3 depends on firebase_storage_web ^3.6.3, google_fonts >=4.0.5 is incompatible with firebase_storage >=11.2.3.
So, because budgets depends on both firebase_storage ^11.2.3 and google_fonts ^5.1.0, version solving failed.